# Jobs from queues wrapping one VPN conection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wrapper, resque, rails-activejob

I have problem with write code for that problem. My application need VPN connection to download some information from another systems.
So, I create multiple jobs to download some informations from another system and each of this jobs should be establish VPN connection, next download data and finally close the connection. I would like to wrap all of these jobs even one that will handle the VPN connection and only one establish ane close connection.

I think that I should be use one queue - 'VPN Jobs' and put there other jobs that will be performed in other queues.

To establish VPN connection i must use jnc ([Juniper network connect](http://www.scc.kit.edu/scc/net/juniper-vpn/linux/)).
I would like to run jobs with ActiveJob and resque.

I hope I explained it come some understandable :)

**Update**
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gepMP.jpg) for better for a better understanding.
 - VPN - Wrapper queue to VPN connection
 - Q1, Q2, Q3 - Queues with some jobs needed vpn connection

Comment: Do you want to establish VPN connection only once (before start Resque)?

Comment: Only one for all jobs in few queue. When all jobs will be done then connestion should be close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use [resque-batched-job](https://github.com/drfeelngood/resque-batched-job) gem for organize your jobs to batches. This gem provide `after_enqueue` and `after_batch` hooks. You can use them for establish and close VPN connection.

I am not a sure exactly but probably this gem has ability to organize nested batches. In this case you can create a main batch job which establish connection to VPN and run nested batch job for uploading images in different queues.

FYI: Sidekiq has the [same functionality (Batch section)](http://sidekiq.org/pro/) out of the box but in Pro version.